# Using Map with multiple text files to change values

Tags: java, file-io

First block of code below import in the file and puts it into a 2 dimensional array. The contents of the file is below.

```
BufferedReader brStudents = null;
BufferedReader brStudents2 = null;
BufferedReader reader = null;

String[][] spaces = new String[11224][4]; 

try
        {

            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("FileMAIN"));

            String line = null;
            int row = 0;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                String[] arrays = line.split(",");
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                {
                    spaces[row][i] = arrays[i];
                }
                row++;
            }
        }
```

`FileMAIN` contains 11442 rows of data, which is laid out like:

```
John, Maths, 534, Green
Sally, Science, 3232, Red
Lilly, Science, 123123, Purple
```

After the array has been imported the code below compares the value in the `value` in `column 0` in `FileONE`, if it is not found in `FileONE` it searches in `FileTWO`. If it is still not found it displays that it is missing.

And example of `FileONE` and `FileTWO` is below

```
try
            {

                    Map<String, String> firstFile = getMapFromCSV("FileONE");
                    Map<String, String> secondFile = getMapFromCSV("FileTWO");
                    int index = 2;

                    for(String[] row : spaces) {
                        String valueToFind = row[index];
                        if(firstFile.containsKey(valueToFind)) {
                            row[index] = firstFile.get(valueToFind);
                        } else if(secondFile.containsKey(valueToFind)) {
                            row[index] = secondFile.get(valueToFind);
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Missing " + valueToFind);
                        }
                    }
```

Example of FileONE or FileTWO

```
123123, UJDJ7D
3232, YHD2H3
534, DSJI3HJ
```

At the end of this, I am not sure how I can not just state that it's missing, but also change the value to the value in the second column.

Example being, the values in `spaces[][]` go from:

```
John, Maths, 534, Green
Sally, Science, 3232, Red
Lilly, Science, 123123, Purple
```

TO:

```
John, Maths, DSJI3HJ, Green
Sally, Science, YHD2H3, Red
Lilly, Science, UJDJ7D, Purple
```

And still display anyone missing.

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Comment: You haven't shown us the `getMapFromCSV` method. Have you checked that it is populating the map correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would implement the `for` loop, I have skipped the use of `contains` and do a `get` directly and validate the result myself. If either `get` calls returns a value I assign it to the current `row`

```
for (String[] row : spaces) {
    String valueToFind = row[index];
    String value = firstFile.get(valueToFind);
    if (value == nil) {
        value = secondFile.get(valueToFind);
    }
    if (value != nil) {
        row[index] = value;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Missing " + valueToFind);
    }
}
```

I don't know the context of this code but I would still recommend you to create a simple POJO class and skip that multi-dimensional array. It makes the code more readable and makes it easier to code in my opinion

```
class Example {
    private String name;
    private String course;
    private String courseId;
    private String color;

    //constructor, get/set methods ..
}
```